# webpack --watch exits after building once

Tags: linux, reactjs, webpack

I was using `webpack --watch` statement to run my webpack in watch mode for building my ReactJS app. However for some reason, it stopped working now. It now just compiles the code once and terminates

I tried the methods suggested in this SO post: [webpack --watch isn't compiling changed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708205/webpack-watch-isnt-compiling-changed-files)

However it did not solve the problem for me. 
Any help is appreaciated

Comment: Does it work with a fresh project or is it completely broken on your system? And are you on OSX?

Comment: @MichaelLyons, It was working earlier, now it doesn't, I am using ubuntu

Comment: run this command: `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p` then run webpack again by `webpack -w`

Comment: Yeah @MayankShukla , I found it on the internet, added that as an answer :) . Thanks anyways

Comment: @MayankShukla, I have added the same link in my question if you see

Comment: ohh missed that part sorry.

Comment: Never mind, it seems you also found the same link that helped me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is webpack --watch not updating when specific files are updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292492/why-is-webpack-watch-not-updating-when-specific-files-are-updated)

Comment: @jdc91, while the question may have addressed the same problem. but none of the solutions on it helped me, and as you can see on the accepted answer here the solution is quite different from all the 3 solutions on that answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem seems to have arose because of the inotify watch limit

> Listen uses inotify by default on Linux to monitor directories for
>   changes. It's not uncommon to encounter a system limit on the number
>   of files you can monitor.

The current watch limit can be seen through the command

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

In my case it was 8192 which is the default value for linux X64 systems

To change it temporarily we need to run the following commands

```
$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

For permanently setting it we should run run

```
$ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: webpack will support an interactive watch mode soon. we are working on this feature.

Answer (score 7):

This happen mostly because it watches the `node_modules` folder and exceeds the limit. In this case, rather than modifying the host system, use:

```
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000,
    ignored: /node_modules/
  }
```

to the `webpack.config.js` exports.

Comment: Still exits after compiling once.