# Webpack dev server can't detect changes in nested folders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I have React app with structure like this:

```
├── components
│   ├── app
│   │   └── App.js
│   ├── grid
│   │   ├── Cell.js
│   │   ├── Grid.js
│   │   └── Row.js
│   └── navbar
│       └── Navbar.js
├── store
│   ├── apartments.js
│   ├── api.js 
│   ├── index.js
│   └── orders.js
├── index.js
├── routes.js
```

when I change something in one of my components files webpack won't compile. But when I change files in "store" folder or `index.js` it'll compile successfully
Here the my config file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
                test: /\.css$/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I tried run `webpack-dev-server` with `--hot` flag.
Also installed `case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin`
Specified `contentBase : __dirname` in dev-server config
it is all didn't help me
My webpack version: `2.6.1`, webpack-dev-server: `2.4.5`
**But sometimes it is just work** and I can't understand why, it is some sort of magic for me. It can work after renaming files and folders or it worked after `case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin` instalation but then stop again.
Please can someone at least explain how I can debug this. I googled problem for two days and didn't find any solution.

Comment: Which OS do you use

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313375/webpack-watch-exits-after-building-once

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it helped. Thank a lot you are my savior!

Comment: I also recently got stuck with this problem, glad it also solved your problem