# Can't import React component from another file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to react and I'm having issues with importing a component from another file.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../resources/styles.scss';
import WelcomeView from '../views/welcome/WelcomeView';

const Root: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <WelcomeView />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

With the above code, I get this error: `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

I've been googling this for hours and everyone has been saying that it's an import issue, but I think I'm using my exports correctly.

Here is the WelcomeView component which I'm trying to import from another file:

```js
import styles from './WelcomeView.scss';
import React from 'react';

const WelcomeView: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.welcome}>
      Welcome
    </div>
  );
};

export default WelcomeView;
```

If I inline WelcomeView in the same file as my Root component, then it works. But doesn't work when it's in a separate file. I think it might have something to do with my tsconfig?

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules":true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true

  },
  "include": ["frontend/src/root/app.tsx"],
}
```

My `package.json` dependencies:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@teamsupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.40.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2"
  }
```

Webpack:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './frontend/src/root/root.tsx',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          '@teamsupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader',
          'css-loader?modules',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: { presets: ['@babel/env'] },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.css', '.scss', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/public/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you extend on your code? There's nothing wrong with what you have posted. And I don't think this is anything to do with tsconfig.

Comment: I've added the rest and also my dependencies in case any of them are old.

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by re-importing the relevant component or by different case among the connected components.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include your entire src folder in tsconfig include.

Comment: Hmm that's a good thought. I changed it to `"include": ["frontend/src/**/*"]` but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is kind of underwhelming, but it turns out the files were corrupt since I'm using OSX. I figured it out from this question:
[webpack --watch isn't compiling changed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708205/webpack-watch-isnt-compiling-changed-files)

I just deleted all the files and then recreated them and it worked.

Comment: Did you do this after you changed the include key?

Comment: Yes but just changing the include key didn't work for me.